# Tapestry, determine if form has errors in tml

Tags: java, tapestry

I have a text in a form that I want to hide if the form has errors and replace it with the error message.
How do i determine in the tml that the current form has an error?

Tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject your form in your java with the @Component annotation, and use the getHasError method. Then you can use this result with the "if" component.

Manu